# refreshing a div without refreshing the page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, refresh

i'm making a setup process to setup a db.
I'm trying to let the user go through all the phases without refreshing the page.
I'm stuck at a point where i want to use the .load() jquery function.
This is the javascript:

```
if(response.error == 'none')
  $("#setup_form").slideToggle('fast', function() {
  $('#setup_form').load('./includes/db_setup_form.php');
  $("#setup_form").delay(1000).slideToggle('fast');
});
```

The if is checking that everything went ok with the previous setup phase.

db_setup_form.php works like this:

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['setup_progress'] == NULL) {?>
Starting phase
<?php } 
else {
 switch ($_SESSION['setup_progress'])
 {
    case "1":?>
    phase 1
    <?php break;

    case "2":?>
        phase 2
    <?php break;

 }
} ?>
```

and this is the main page:

```
<div id="setup_form">
  <?php include('./includes/db_setup_form.php'); ?>
</div>
```

The $_SESSION['setup_progress'] variable is given after the user completes the first setup phase.
The problem is that everything works if i manually refresh the page once the first installation phase is done but the javascript does not seem to work, the div gets displayed without the updated informations.

thanks
From what i know everything should be ok...but it is not.

Comment: don't forget that $.load() or any ajax request are asynchronos
so the rest of the code will keep going even if the request didn't finished yet or even if the request fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should provide a valid url instead of a path. So:

```
.load('./includes/db_setup_form.php');
```

should be

```
.load('/includes/db_setup_form.php');
```

Comment: tried that, for no reason it made the animation smoother but still it didnt load the updated content.

Comment: doing this gives me a 404 error tho but i'm sure the path is correct.

Comment: alright... then you've specified the wrong path/url. Can you browse to the file like http://localhost/includes/db_setup_form.php and see what happens

Comment: Yes, i can. And it works. But still not working with js... it's a mistery.

Comment: Ok, after some tries i managed to get it almost done. The file path must be written without / before the path (includes/db_setup_form.php).
Now the problem is that the session variables don't work when calling the php page with .load(), they do work manually refrehsing the page tho.
The only working way i found was using some $_GET variables but i'd prefer using session variables, do you know why it doesn't work with session variables?

Comment: after rewatching your code I noticed you're db_setup_form.php doesn't start/contain a `session_start()`?

Comment: Indeed, that was the problem.
Fixed long ago but forgot to post it here.
Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

> You missed DIV ID in the end of your .load

```
$('#setup_form').load('./includes/db_setup_form.php #setup_form');
```