# How to refresh the contents without reloading page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to refresh the contents of page without reloading the page in javascript.
This is not working.

```
window.location.assign("#/invoice/" + $scope.invoiceId);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021481/refreshing-a-div-without-refreshing-the-page


This might help you.

Comment: Can u be more clear about your question try doing like below var url = '/Candidate/'+newpageIndex
        $location.path(url);

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX. jQuery provides a nice wrapper for that.

http://jQuery.com/

This example loads ajax/test.html into you #content div:

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
     $("#content").html(data);
});
```